# pragma base - warnings question

Tags: perl, warnings, pragma

When I run this, why do I not get the `Attempting to inherit from yourself generates a warning.` ([base#DIAGNOSTICS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?base#DIAGNOSTICS))?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use 5.012;

{
    package MyWebServer;

    use HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
    use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect it is a documentation bug.

The test file `t/base.t` shows this type of a scenario to get the warning:

```
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use 5.012;

package Foo;
use base 'Foo';

__END__

Class 'Foo' tried to inherit from itself
```

You could patch the POD and submit it as a [Bug Report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Report.html?Queue=base).

Since [base](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html) is a Core pragma, you could instead submit a [perlbug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlbug.html) (not sure which is preferred).

Comment: Yes, the docs should have said `package Foo` instead of `use Foo` there.

Comment: Note that this is already fixed in bleadperl and will be part of 5.14.0.

Answer (score 5):

Err, because you aren't trying to inherit from yourself?

That would be this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use 5.012;

{
    package HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI;
    use base qw(HTTP::Server::Simple::CGI);
    ...
```

base should be phased out in favor of the newer, less gimmicky [parent](http://p3rl.org/parent).